# Quando o sorteio é feito, o programa retorna os valores iniciais das variaveis como resultado (a = none, b = none...), como posso resolver?

Tags: python

import random

x = 1

while x == 1:

```
q = int(input('Quantos alunos serão sorteados? De 1 - 10 '))  

a = None  
b = None  
c = None  
d = None  
e = None  
f = None  
g = None  
h = None  
i = None  
j = None  

lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]  

if q == 1:  
    lis = [a]  
elif q == 2:  
    lis = [a, b]  
elif q == 3:
    lis = [a, b, c]
elif q == 4:
    lis = [a, b, c, d]
elif q == 5:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e]
elif q == 6:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
elif q == 7:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
elif q == 8:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
elif q == 9:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
elif q == 10:
    lis = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
else:
    print('Valor invalido, reiniciando processo.')
    (exit())

msg = 'Qual o nome do aluno(a)?'

if q == 1:
    a = input(msg)
elif q == 2:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
elif q == 3:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
elif q == 4:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
elif q == 5:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
elif q == 6:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
    f = input(msg)
elif q == 7:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
    f = input(msg)
    g = input(msg)
elif q == 8:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
    f = input(msg)
    g = input(msg)
    h = input(msg)
elif q == 9:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
    f = input(msg)
    g = input(msg)
    h = input(msg)
    i = input(msg)
elif q == 10:
    a = input(msg)
    b = input(msg)
    c = input(msg)
    d = input(msg)
    e = input(msg)
    f = input(msg)
    g = input(msg)
    h = input(msg)
    i = input(msg)
    j = input(msg)

z = random.choice(lis)

print('O aluno sorteado foi {}'.format(z))

y = int(input('Deseja sortear novamente? 1 = sim 2 = não'))
if y == 1:
    x = 1
elif y == 2:
    exit()
elif y != 1 or 2:
    print('Valor invalido. Encerrando o processo')
    exit()
```

Answer (score -2):

Você não precisa setar uma variável para cada aluno.
Utilize apenas uma variavel do tipo lista, onde serão armazenados os nomes dos alunos, e ao final, pegue um item aleatório da lista de nomes.

a vantagem de utlizar uma variável do tipo lista é que você pode ir adicionando nomes conforme necessário, o código fica mais legivel e fácil de ser compreendido.

assim, cada aluno ficaria em uma posição na lista, como por exemplo:

`alunos = ['Alberto', 'Carlos', 'Jaqueline', 'Francisco', 'Maria', 'Karen']...`

algo desse tipo:

```
import random

# pergunta quantos alunos vão ter na lista
q = int(input('Quantos alunos serão sorteados? (Digite o número com a quantidade de alunos): '))

# inicia uma variavel do tipo lista
nomes = []

# faz um loop de N vezes o numero de alunos
for n in range(q):
    # pergunta o nome do aluno
    nome = input('Digite o nome do aluno {}: '.format(n + 1))
    
    # inclui o nome ao final da lista
    nomes.append(nome)

# seleciona um aluno aleatorio
aluno_sorteado = random.choice(nomes)

# apresenta o aluno sorteado
print('O aluno sorteado foi {}'.format(aluno_sorteado))
```

Comment: sei la pq recebi um downvote nisso. se possível, deixar o motivo pelo downvote! a questão original não diz nenhum requisito, como se pode utilizar listas, tudo em variáveis diferentes, etc.